# Ember: Use Google Maps-API in Ember

Tags: google-maps, ember.js

There are just one or two tutorials outhere about how to use gmaps-API in ember-cli.

See this:
http://blog.atmartin.io/google-maps-integration-ember-cli-edition/

Unfortunately there are problems after a few days using this approach. When starting my application, it seems like nothing happens in the gmaps-api. When downloading the JS-File again like described within the tutorial
(`curl -o vendor/gmaps.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY-HERE`)
from above, it works again.

1. How could that be?

Also I'm wondering about the *async*-Tag in the general approach from google itself. The GMaps Team shows examples of using GMaps like this:

`<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY-HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>`

2. Is there a difference (maybe not async) in loading the API as downloaded file via Brocfile.js as mentioned in the tutorial from above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your trying to use use the google maps API in a ember app i would highly recommend this Addon:

http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-google-map

it works very well you can also find a demo here: http://huafu.github.io/ember-google-map/

and here is the wiki: https://github.com/huafu/ember-google-map/wiki

you can install it as an addon via:

```
ember install ember-google-map
```

Comment: I would suggest to use it as Ember Addon: http://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-google-map

Answer (score 2):

That tutorials suggestion to copy the Google Maps Javascript API v3 to your local server:

```
curl -o vendor/gmaps.js https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY-HERE
```

is against the Google Maps Javascript API v3 terms of use and will not work reliably.

Comment: So what would you suggest how to include the gmaps-api?

Comment: The documented way. `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>` (for the release version)